# Google Calendar api v3 using asp.net

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

I am planing to integrate google calendar v3 api.  i have Install the NuGet package Google.Apis.calendar.v3 package and i got the sample from the google

```
  Dim credential As UserCredential
    Using stream As New FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                New FileDataStore("Calendar.VB.Sample")).Result
    End Using
```

there they specified to give the client and secret id in the client_secrets.josn file. while executing the code it take me to the browser and ask for login details. After login it show me the error as invalid return url.

is there any other way to specify the call back url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create a project in the Google API Console there you must have created an oAuth2.0 clientID where you defined the RedirectUri.

So go in the Google API Console (http://code.google.com/apis/console) and change it to the correct Uri.

NB If working in the development environment make sure you use a fixed IP port otherwise you have to change the Uri every time you build and run your project.